# Composite ViewModel and UpdateModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What is missing that restuls in unpopulated values in POST action?

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var productPageViewModel = new ProductPageViewModel();

    productPageViewModel.ProductPageCriteria = BuildProductPageCriteriaViewModel();
    productPageViewModel.Products = GetProducts(productPageViewModel.ProductPageCriteria);

    return View(productPageViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProductPageViewModel productPageViewModel, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    // productPageViewModel is not populated with posted values of ProductPageCriteria.CategoryID, ProductPageCriteria.DepartmentID and ProductPageCriteria.PageSize
    // formCollection has correct values
    // Calling UpdateModel(productPageViewModel); has no affect - makes sense, the framework has already called it
    // Calling UpdateModel(productPageViewModel.ProductPageCriteria); populates the values.
    // The renderd form has names like CategoryID, DepartmentID unlike ProductPageCriteria.CategoryID, ProductPageCriteria.DepartmentID
    //     if the top model was passed to all partial views also.

    return View(productPageViewModel);
}
```

Models

```
public class ProductPageCriteriaViewModel
{
    public const int DefaultPageSize = 15;

    public ProductPageCriteriaViewModel()
    {
        Categories = new List<Category>();
        Departments = new List<Department>();

        PageSize = DefaultPageSize;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Page Size")]
    public int? PageSize { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPageViewModel
{
    public ProductPageViewModel()
    {
        ProductPageCriteria = new ProductPageCriteriaViewModel();
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public ProductPageCriteriaViewModel ProductPageCriteria { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

View Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.Partial("_ProductCriteria", Model.ProductPageCriteria)

    @Html.Partial("_ProductList", Model.Products)
}
```

Partial View _ProductCriteria.cshtml

```
@model Mvc3Application4.Models.ProductPageCriteriaViewModel

<fieldset>
    <legend>Criteria</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryID, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName", Model.CategoryID), "--- All ---")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentID, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName", Model.DepartmentID), "--- All ---")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageSize)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PageSize, new SelectList(new List<int> {10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 100}.Select(n => new {Value = n, Text = n}), "Value", "Text", Model.PageSize), "--- All ---")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PageSize)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Partial View _ProductList.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Mvc3Application4.Models.Product>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            ProductName
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ProductID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ProductID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ProductID })
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.ProductName
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: If I add a call to UpdateModel(productPageViewModel.ProductPageCriteria); the submodel (ProductPageCriteria) is updated. The form inputs don't have any decoration in the name so it makes sens why it works this way. Is it the right way? Any other way?

Comment: Could you tell me why you have FormCollection as your second parameter?

Comment: For this question, it can be ignored. Presence or absence of it doesn't make any difference. I added it to validate that all submitted values (verified in fiddler) indeed show up to the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is off the top of my head and untested, but I believe if you pass the parent model (`ProductPageViewModel`) to the products criteria partial view, change the partial view to inherit this model, and change the controls to use from `model => model.ProductPageCriteria.CategoryID` instead of `model => model.CategoryID`, it should maintain the naming so that UpdateModel can match up the fields with the posted values.

Sorry for the extreme run-on sentence and if this is incorrect I'm sure I'll earn my Peer Pressure badge pretty quickly. :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that works fine. In fact that is how I had it earlier. To refactor, I wanted to have the views to be dependent on the smaller models i.e. use only what they need. For example in this case, the _ProductCriteria.cshtml doesn't need more than ProductPageCriteriaViewModel. I could make it also work, it is just that I had to call UpdateModel for each of the submodels. I would like to know if this is correct way and this is the way others handle it too.

Comment: I'm not an expert on MVC best practices, but I believe that the main view renders the partial views into the page before the data is past in from the controller. Since the main view inherits the the parent veiwmodel passing the child viewmodel would be the same as passing the parent viewmodel except for the name that is generated for it. I could be completely wrong on this, but this is how I think of the process. I'd be interested in hearing others responses though.